# How can my front-end access files from the file storage of my back-end if they're separated? Should my database table contains file name or file path?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

Lets say I am creating a Node.js API and one of my database models/tables looks like this:

```
Table: servers
Columns: id, name, image
```

So the image column of that table should contain some sort of reference to the image file of that server.

Inside the function which creates a server entry to the database, I set the value of that column to the name of the image file. For example a record might look like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Server1',
    image: 'server1.png'
}
```

When my front-end makes a `GET` request to the `/servers` endpoint, the back-end returns all servers. I then would like to loop over them and render the name and image of the server. My problem is that on the front-end I only know the name of the image, without the actual path to that image.

I just can't wrap my head around this. I was thinking that maybe I have to set the value of the image column to an actual URL which will be the path + file name instead of the file name but I'm not sure.